# Google Doc, replacing a string screws with the formatting

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have some simple app script that adds paragraph numbers to each paragraph (Google Doc). I also have a function that deletes these numbers if I add intervening paragraphs and therefore need to renumber the whole thing.

When I run this delete function it successfully deletes the numbers but the formatting of replaced paragraphs is screwed about - some are bolded, some are smaller pointed. Does anyone know why? I think it's shifting formatting from previous or later text, as the formatting does change throughout, like any doc.

```
function deleteParagraphNumbers() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraph = body.getParagraphs();

  paragraph.forEach((p) => {
    var text = p.getText();
    if (text.trim() !== ""
      && /^\d+\./.test(text)) {
      var newText = text.replace(/^\d+\. /, "")
      p.setText(newText);
    }
  })
};  // this does odd things to the formatting of some of the lines, but generally works.
```

I've considered delete the number as supposed to replace(), but I don't know of a method that does this. Slice() would return just the number, and I think the fact that a new variable has to be created and stored with replace() might be the issue, but I don't know.

Comment: What does the replaced part look like that looks odd? Maybe that is by itself part of other fomatting that now breaks because the numbers are removed? Can't you shorten that to `p.setText(p.getText().replace(/^\d+\. /, ""))`

Comment: What you are doing is getting the text as a string.  This contains no formatting.  You should be looking at [editAsText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#editAsText())

Comment: Thanks All. Sorry, not sure if this is the correct way to respond. @TheWizEd has the solution. Thanks for the insite. editAsText().deleteText() will do it once you've found the length of each match.